# Explicitly Computing Structure Sheaves For Quotients of Polynomial Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, sheaf-theory, schemes

I'm working through an introductory problem in scheme theory and just want to make sure I'm understanding the concepts correctly.  The problem states to consider the following two rings, specify their Zariski open sets, as well as the restriction maps:

- $A = \mathbb{C}[t]/\left (t^2-t\right) = \{a+bt \; | \; a,b\in\mathbb{C}\}$
- $B = \mathbb{C}[t]/\left (t^3-t^2\right) = \{a+bt+ct^2 \; | \; a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}\}$

For ring $A$ we can compute $X_A = \text{Spec} A = \left \{\widetilde{(t)}, \widetilde{(t-1)}\right \}$ where the $\sim$ is to signify that we are really dealing with the quotients $\widetilde{(t)} = (t)/\left (t^2-t\right )$.  I arrived at this since prime ideals in a ring $R/I$ are projections of prime ideals of $R$ containing $I$.  Furthermore, I concluded that the Zariski topology on $X_A$ is discrete since both prime ideals can be written as the zero set of an ideal (namely itself) in $A$.  At the risk of overdoing the notation I'll call the open sets $U_t$ and $U_{t-1}$, then the structure sheaf elements should be

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{O}(U_t) & = & A_{\widetilde{(t)}} \;\; =\;\; \left \{\left .\frac{a+bt}{c+dt} \;\right | \; c+dt \not \in \widetilde{(t)}\right \} \\
\mathcal{O}(U_{t-1}) & = & A_{\widetilde{(t-1)}} \;\; =\;\; \left \{\left .\frac{a+bt}{c+dt} \;\right | \; c+dt \not \in \widetilde{(t-1)}\right \}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Is my logic more or less correct?  We as well have that $U_t \cap U_{t-1} = \emptyset$ so we need not worry about the sheaf element in that case.

For ring $B$ much of my logic remains the same in that $X_B = \text{Spec} B = \left \{\widetilde{(t)}, \widetilde{(t-1)}\right \}$, this is discrete as well for similar reasons, and the only difference is in the forms of the structure sheaf elements:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{O}(U_t) & = & B_{\widetilde{(t)}} \;\; =\;\; \left \{\left .\frac{a+bt+ct^2}{d+ft+gt^2} \;\right | \; d+ft+gt^2 \not \in \widetilde{(t)}\right \} \\
\mathcal{O}(U_{t-1}) & = & B_{\widetilde{(t-1)}} \;\; =\;\; \left \{\left .\frac{a+bt+ct^2}{d+ft+gt^2} \;\right | \; d+ft+gt^2 \not \in \widetilde{(t-1)}\right \}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I'm studying algebraic geometry for the first time out of Bosch's *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*, and I also don't have much of an algebra background aside from groups, Lie groups, and basic ring theory.

**Response to Comments**

I think I caught KReiser's comment about the denominators in ring $B$ being incorrect.  In response to the comments about rationalization, for ring $A$ we can take

$$
\frac{a+bt}{c+dt} \;\; =\;\; \frac{at+bt^2}{ct+dt^2} \;\; =\;\; \frac{at+bt}{ct+dt} \;\; =\;\; \frac{a+b}{c+d}
$$

which means that both sheaf elements in ring $A$ are just copies of $\mathbb{C}$.  So can we conclude that $\mathcal{O}(U_t) \cong \mathbb{C}$ as well as $\mathcal{O}(U_{t-1}) \cong \mathbb{C}$?

Moving on to ring $B$ we can similarly compute

$$
\frac{a+bt+ct^2}{d+ft+gt^2} \;\; =\;\; \frac{at^2 + bt^3 +gt^4}{dt^2+ft^3+gt^4} \;\; =\;\; \frac{a+b+c}{d+f+g}
$$

so, do we get the same result for ring $B$?

Comment: Part 1 is correct but could be more correct: you can rationalize denominators. Part 2 has bugs (look at the denominators).

Comment: @KReiser Can you elaborate a little more?  I'm really not sure what you mean by "rationalize".  As in, make the denominators have real coefficients?  For part 2 the bugs aren't jumping out at me.  I'm not an algebraist by training and this is all self-study, so if there are norms algebraists have I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Here "rationalizing the denominator" should get rid of all appearances of $t$ in the denominator. For example, the coset of $t$ is invertible in $A_{\widetilde{(t-1)}}$, and you can simplify
$$\frac1{c+dt}=\frac{t}{ct+dt^2}=\frac{t}{ct+dt}=\frac1{c+d}$$ also taking advantage of the fact that in $A$ the cosets of $t$ and $t^2$ are equal.

Comment: And the same argument shows that in $A_{\widetilde{(t-1)}}$ the numerator $a+bt=a+b$ :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So would this mean that $\mathcal{O}(U_t) \cong \mathbb{C\times C}$ since we would get $\frac{a+bt}{c+dt} = \frac{at + bt^2}{ct+dt^2} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$?  I understand what you're saying about rationalizing, but I don't see if anything distinguishes $\mathcal{O}(U_t)$ from $\mathcal{O}(U_{t-1})$, at least for ring $A$.  I need to look at part 2 more deeply.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I made edits to my question to reflect these comments on rationalization.  I also corrected the mistake that KReiser was mentioning.

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have
$$A\simeq \Bbb{C}[t]/(t)\oplus \Bbb{C}[t]/(t-1).$$
The two summands on the right are, indeed, both isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$. The distinction comes from the fact that the element $t$ is in the coset of $0$ in the former summand and in the coset of $1$ in the latter. This reflects the fact that $A$ is, so to speak, the coordinate ring $\Gamma[V]$ of the algebraic set $V=\{0,1\}\subset\Bbb{A}^1$, and the coordinate function $t$ exactly distinguishes the two points. The ring $B$, on the other hand, has more going on, and brings extra structure to $t=0$.

Comment: Do observe that the prime ideals of that direct sum of rings $\Bbb{C}\oplus\Bbb{C}$ are generated by $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ respectively. Each component "missing the other" after localization.